# Rails Factory Bot accessing passed values inside factory definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is there a way to access values that are passed into the create method inside a factory definition?

For example

```
create(:user, name: "Jon")
```

Is there a way to check in the after(:create) hook if a name was passed or if it is default one?

Comment: You know the hook. Why don't you try and let us know what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compare the attributes, like:

`user.name == FactoryBot.attributes_for(:user)[:name]`